# template function that deduces both containers and initializer_list-s

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, initializer-list

I'd like to write a helper function like:

```
template <typename F, typename Range1, typename Range2>
auto helper(const Range1& left, const Range2& right, F&& pred)
{
    using namespace std; // for cbegin/cend and ADL
    return pred(cbegin(left), cend(left), cbegin(right), cend(right));
}
```

It works well for containers:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::vector<int> v2 = {5,4,3,2,1,6};

std::cout << helper(v1, v2, [](const auto&... args){ return std::is_permutation(args...);}) << std::endl;
```

but it fails to deduce `initializer_list`-s ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7d6418d96a405b8)):

```
std::cout << helper({1,2,3,4,5,6}, {5,4,3,2,1,6}, [](const auto&... args){ return std::is_permutation(args...);}) << std::endl;
```

Is there an idiomatic way to rewrite `helper` so that it deduces both containers and `initializer_list`-s?

I can't come up with anything better than [overloads for all combinations of container and `initializer_list`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa2483ace5cc094a).

Comment: Too bad class template deduction can't apply to a function parameter. If the number of function parameters that should accept either syntax gets bigger than 2 or 3, I'd look for a way to define the `2**P` overloads using Boost.Preprocessor...

Comment: Unfortunately, as everyone else has pointed out, if you want to use your helper function with `initializer_list`s in a oneliner, there is nothing you can do other than overloading. However, if you are willing to use `auto` and create the `initializer_list` before the helper function (as in the `vector`s example above), then it will work. Have a look here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e90320470afdf12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the fundamental problem here is that a *braced-init-list* like `{ 1, 2, 3 }` is just an *initializer* and not an object of type `std::initializer_list<T>`. It can potentially be used to initialize an object of some given type. But it's not an object of any type itself. And there doesn't seem to be anything in the [rules for function template argument deduction](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call) that would allow you to get an `std::initializer_list<T>` from a *braced-init-list* argument unless your function parameter was already declared to be some sort of `std::initializer_list<T>` to begin with.

So I'm afraid writing those overloads will be the simplest solution…

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best I can do:

```
template<class X>
struct Range {
  X* container;
  Range(X& x):container(std::addressof(x)) {}
  Range(X&& x):container(std::addressof(x)) {} // dangerous, but hey
  auto begin() const { using std::begin; return begin(*container); }
  auto end() const { using std::end; return end(*container); }
  auto cbegin() const { using std::cbegin; return cbegin(*container); }
  auto cend() const { using std::cend; return cend(*container); }
};

template<class T>
struct Range<std::initializer_list<T>> {
  using X=std::initializer_list<T>;
  X container;
  Range(X x):container(x) {}
  auto begin() const { using std::begin; return begin(container); }
  auto end() const { using std::end; return end(container); }
  auto cbegin() const { using std::cbegin; return cbegin(container); }
  auto cend() const { using std::cend; return cend(container); }
};

template<class T>
Range( std::initializer_list<T> ) -> Range<std::initializer_list< T >>;

template<class C1, class C2>
void foo( Range<C1> r1, Range<C2> c2 ) {}
```

test code:

```
Range r = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}};
(void)r;
std::vector v = {1,2,3};
foo( Range{{'a','b','c'}}, Range{v} );
```

you have to cast the arguments to `Range` manually for this to work at the call site, because class template arguement deduction doesn't work on function arguments.

---

We might be able to attack it differently.

```
template <typename F, typename Range1, typename Range2>
auto helper(const Range1& left, const Range2& right, F&& pred)
```

change the above syntax to a chained-call.

```
helper(v1)({1,2,3})[pred];
```

that reduces the 2^n explosion into 2.  Not much of a help with 2 overloads, but still...

```
template<class...Ts>
struct helper_t {
  std::tuple<Ts&&...> containers;
  template<class T>
  helper_t<T, Ts...> operator()(T&& t)&& {
    return { /* append-move containers and t into one tuple */ };
  }
  template<class T>
  helper_t<std::initializer_list<T>, Ts...> operator()(std::initializer_list<T> t)&& {
    return { /* append-move containers and t into one tuple */ };
  }
  template<class F>
  decltype(auto) operator[](F&& f)&& {
    return std::move(*this).apply_impl(
      std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{},
      std::forward<F>(f)
    );
  }
private:
  template<std::size_t...Is, class F>
  decltype(auto) apply_impl( std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f ) && {
    using std::cbegin; using std::cend;
    using std::get;
    return std::forward<F>(f)(
      cbegin( get<Is>(std::move(containers)) ), cend( get<Is>(std::move(containers)) )
    );
  }
};
static constexpr const helper_t<> helper;
```

I left appending the tuples as an exercise.

```
helper( container1 )( {1,2,3} )( container2 )[ some_lambda ];
```

is the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please explicitly specify that the arguments you are passing is the initializer_list like this:-

```
std::cout << helper(v1, std::initializer_list<int>{5,4,3,2,1,6}, [](const auto&... args){ return std::is_permutation(args...);}) << std::endl;
std::cout << helper(std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6}, std::initializer_list<int>{5,4,3,2,1,6}, [](const auto&... args){ return std::is_permutation(args...);}) << std::endl;
```

This is the way you can pass the initializer_list else you need to overload  for all combinations of container and initializer_list

Comment: I don't think that this solution qualifies as 'idiomatic'.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Michael Kenzel, the problem is that a braced-init-list isn't an `std::intializer_list`.

So I'm agree with Michael (+1): I don't see a way to write a single template function that can deduce both STL containers and (as `std::initilizer_list<T>`) braced-init-lists.

But if you can accept to add an `helper()` helper function for your `helper()` function, you can use the fact that a braced-init-list can be deduced as a C-style array.

So you can write a `helper()` specific version for C-style arrays that can convert the C-style arrays in `std::initializer_list` (or `std::array`, or... see you) or, in my example, you can simply call your original `helper()` function passing the arrays but explicating the types.

I mean: you can add this `helper()` helper function

```
template <typename F, typename R1, std::size_t S1,
                      typename R2, std::size_t S2>
auto helper (R1 const (&r1)[S1], R2 const (&r2)[S2], F && pred)
 { return helper<F, R1[S1], R2[S2]>(r1, r2, std::forward<F>(pred)); }
```

Drawback: this works if both ranges are STL containers or if both ranges are C-style arrays (or braced-init-lists); if you can have a STL container and a C-style array, you have to write other two `helper()` helper function: one for (only) the first range and one for (only) the second.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename F, typename Range1, typename Range2>
auto helper (Range1 const & left, Range2 const & right, F && pred)
 { return pred(std::cbegin(left), std::cend(left),
               std::cbegin(right), std::cend(right)); }

template <typename F, typename R1, std::size_t S1,
                      typename R2, std::size_t S2>
auto helper (R1 const (&r1)[S1], R2 const (&r2)[S2], F && pred)
 { return helper<F, R1[S1], R2[S2]>(r1, r2, std::forward<F>(pred)); }

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
   std::vector<int> v2 = {5,4,3,2,1,6};

   std::cout << helper(v1, v2,
      [](auto const & ... args){ return std::is_permutation(args...);})
      << std::endl;

   std::cout << helper({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6},
      [](auto const &... args){ return std::is_permutation(args...);})
      << std::endl;
 }
```